# Typescript mapped return type: intersection reduced to never, conflicting intersection property

Tags: typescript, intersection, discriminated-union, mapped-types

Goal: make the return type of a function based upon the input type using a mapped type to lookup the return type.

Problem: I get an error because of the conflicts in intersection of discriminated union types, which I conceptually understand but am at a loss on how to structure my types to achieve the my goal.

```
Type 'Integration' is not assignable to type 'IntegrationTypeData[T]'.
  Type 'IntegrationA' is not assignable to type 'IntegrationTypeData[T]'.
    Type 'IntegrationA' is not assignable to type 'never'.
      The intersection 'IntegrationA & IntegrationB' was reduced to 'never' because property 'name' has conflicting types in some constituents.
```

My type look like the following:

```
enum Integrations {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B',
}

type IntegrationMap<M extends { [key: string]: any }> = {
  [Key in keyof M]: M[Key]
};

type IntegrationA = {
  name: Integrations.A,
  propertyA: string;
}

type IntegrationB = {
  name: Integrations.B,
  propertyB: number;
}

type IntegrationData = {
  [Integrations.A]: IntegrationA;
  [Integrations.B]: IntegrationB;
};

// this resolves to type Integration = IntegrationA | IntegrationB
type Integration = IntegrationMap<IntegrationData>[keyof IntegrationMap<IntegrationData>];


// the function I want to make have a dynamic/mapped return type
const getIntegration = <T extends Integrations>(name: T): IntegrationData[T] => {
  // the type of the integrations variable is Integration[]
  const integration = integrations.find((i: Integration) => i.name === name);
  return integration;
};

// desired usage
// typeof intB = IntegrationB
const intB = getIntegration(Integrations.B);
```

Can someone help me understand how to resolve this error and how to properly type the data so that I get a dynamic and type safe return type of this function?

Comment: In this case the compiler doesn't understand that the callback `(i: Integration) => i.name === name` serves to identify an `IntegrationData[T]`.  If you annotate it with a type predicate like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8Lz4w) it works.  Oh and you have to assert that `find()` returns something because in general it might be `undefined`.  Does that solution work for you?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz This does work, thank you! I'd love to do a deeper dive into how exactly this works and why my original attempt didn't. I'd be extremely grateful for any resource you might have handy or recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of the `integrations` array are of the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `(IntegrationA | IntegrationB)`.

If you look at [the default call signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0df46e873322b8eeb271a442eaf034d91ae68770/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L32) for the [`find()` method of arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), you'll see that it returns a value of either the element type (`IntegrationA | IntegrationB` in this case) or `undefined`.  So you are returning a value of type `IntegrationA | IntegrationB | undefined`.  But since your function's return type is `IntegrationData[T]` where `T` is the type of the `name` argument passed in.  The compiler cannot be sure that the former is assignable to the latter, so it complains.

The particular error message you get talks about the [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `IntegrationA & IntegrationB` being reduced to [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) because the only way to be sure that you're returning an `Integration[T]` *independently* of `T` is if your value were both an `IntegrationA` *and* an `IntegrationB`, which is impossible.  It's probably best not to get too caught up in the error message.

Suffice it to say that the problem here is that `find()`'s return type is too wide for your purposes.

---

Luckily for you there is [another call signature for `find()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0df46e873322b8eeb271a442eaf034d91ae68770/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L31) which has the potential to return a *narrower* type than the array element type (but still possibly `undefined`).  If the callback you pass in is a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) with a return type predicate of the form `x is Y`, then will return the narrowed type `Y | undefined`.

It would be nice if the compiler could understand that `i => i.name === name` acts as a type guard function with call signature `(i: Integration) => i is IntegrationData[T]`.  Unfortunately this does not happen; TypeScript does not infer type guard function call signatures from implementations.  There is an open request at [microsoft/TypeScript#38390](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38390) to support this in some cases, but for now it's not part of the language.  (And even if it were, such inference in this situation might be beyond its abilities.)

If you want to use `i => i.name === name` as a type guard function you need to [annotate it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) as such:

```
const getIntegration = <T extends Integrations>(name: T): IntegrationData[T] => {
  const integration = integrations.find(
    (i: Integration): i is IntegrationData[T] => i.name === name
  // annotated ---> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  );
  return integration!;
};
```

The annotation gets you most of the way there.  It still doesn't eliminate `undefined`, though.  For all the compiler knows, `integrations` doesn't actually have an element of the type `IntegrationData[T]` in it.  So `integration` might be `undefined`.  You can handle this explicitly, by writing `if (!integration) throw new Error("OH NO I WAS WRONG")` before `return`.  Or, if you're sure it won't actually be `undefined`, you can tell the compiler that by using a [non-null assertion operator (!)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-).  Writing `return integration!`, you're claiming that `integration` will not be `undefined` or `null`, and thus the value of type `IntegrationData[T] | undefined` can be treated like an `IntegrationData[T]`.

And now it compiles with no error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYOwrgtgBAkiAuwDmAnAhvAlgexAZygG8AoKKAQSgF4oByc2gGlKgCFq7WniBfY4+AE8ADsFgJk6LLgCyaYQB4ZUYAA9EIACYFCUANoBrYIIBcUPPBSYQSALpm0IQVB4A+DiTJ6A0sajWoI0FsADMoGXtwn2NbXgBufiFRcURUDBwQShpPKBA0CGAzOFSpDLwAOnJmMmEUbFEUIXIzCysbBL4BETFiyXTcdmyWPIKiiTTpfHLWaqha+uBGwVYzcAgAI0WOxO6UvsmAEQw0DxY9XomyysiL0txyBK9b-qnWG-G7kFYOhOIAej+UHgAAtMAQUMA8NgADYAN0hQOwQN2z0mHFRGUoAB89pcBl1khjcOiPi85IoiSAjvA0K5DMZQrjPuSFJTqbTbAkAcjCaS0TRKdimS9WPxNMAAMbQtAQqAS3AWfx8spjEovPSxf6AkFiEJgEAStEwKAAd0c8ERUAgaCMUGBaHhUBOmkEI0wEr+1uEok0UAh8DAKBAPOAxHl+AtSGA8EpHAUABUVOpQNphZM8K4ABQjQpQeMASlV+wy7L08ds1HcOXDiusav5SvrVxC1k0mczmCLeJAhf8-gIbOOZYrVHcmHKOeoVBoOfzjz90cDwbrxdwAEIfvxueK8JgIb6wHg0FGtSHGXXBmmMqKaxaLxwozHlbhM5SKqw50A)